# Disk usage command df not showing the expected values in output

Tags: disk-space

The `df /data` command is not showing the exact disk usage information.

This is what I get as output:

```
Filesystem  1K-blocks  Used     Available Use%   Mounted on /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lvol0  

            41153856   2099892  36956812  6%     /data
```

Actually when I issued `lvdisplay` this partition shows 40GB. But when I converted this KiB or KB into GiB it’s not giving the correct output. And may I know inode size is included, also just tell me is there any reserved spaces are there for a partition.

I also checked the inode size using `tune2fs -l` command for /data partition and it's showing `inode size = 256 bytes`.

The Reserved Block Count is `524288`.

The actual difference is (40 GiB) 41943040 KiB - 41153856 (output from "#df /data") is equal to 789184 KiB. Please tell me why this much difference.

Comment: I'd bet [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185894/44760) answers your question. Basically the number of available blocks is not the same as the total volume size due to some overhead in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

All filesystems have overhead; which comes of the need to keep track of:

- where data is stored,
- attributes (read-only, access rights, ...)
- filenames,
- folders
- and their relationships
- and how to find them QUICKLY (hashes)
- ... (more, e.g. journaling, depending on filesystem)

... on top of the data that you store on the partition/disk/volume/...

The posting [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185894/44760) provided by zagrimsan (comment on the Q) has a lot of detail on the above.

Also consider deleted files that are still open, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/974960/why-dont-du-and-df-agree-on-aws-ephemeral-storage)

Comment: is there any calculation or command to find the filesystem overhead that you have mentioned

Comment: updated the answer.